# `context` function not executing NextJs / Apollo / GraphQL

Tags: next.js, apollo, apollo-server

I have the following Apollo setup

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { handleAuth } from '../../api/helpers/AuthenticationHelpers/handleAuth';
import resolvers from '../../api/graphql/resolvers';
const typeDefs = require("../../api/graphql/schema");

const createContext = async ({ req }) => {
  console.log("Handling Context");
  console.log("REQUEST::::", req);
  return { user: null }; // Simplify the logic for testing
};


const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  context: createContext,
});

export { apolloServer };
```

That I then export and input into this file, where I start it up...

```
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';
import { apolloServer } from "./server"

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(apolloServer);
```

I have also tried doing it the following way, according to [Apollo Official Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#context-initialization-function) and [Next/Apollo Integration Docs](https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-next)

```
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';
import { apolloServer } from "./server"

const createContext = async ({ req }) => {
  console.log("Handling Context");
  console.log("REQUEST::::", req); // Add this line for debugging

  if (!req || !req.headers) {
    console.error("Request object or headers undefined");
    return { user: null };
  }

  const token = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!token) {
    return { user: null };
  }

  const user = await handleAuth(token);
  return user;
};

export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(apolloServer, {context: createContext});
```

Both variations do not work.

I can access the API perfectly fine, I can send requests for mutations and queries so everything is working as expected except for my context function not firing. The logs are never displayed no matter what I do. When this *was* working, it was logging the context every 2 or so seconds. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apollo Server 4 does not have that `context` option - if you are using TypeScript, you should get a warning here.

This is documented [here in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#context-initialization-function).

Instead, you would pass the `context` as an argument to e.g. `expressMiddleware` or `startStandaloneServer`.